# Queue-like object for multiprocessing synchronization

Tags: python, multiprocessing, synchronization, queue

I have a Python program that I'm writing using multiprocessing. I have an object that needs to exist in multiple processes, but I need all the objects in all the processes to stay synced. I had the thought to use a multiprocessing queue to have the object in one process broadcast to its counterparts in other processes what changes it is making (e.g. appending to a list field on the object), but I don't think queues are the best thing to handle this behavior since each queue item should only be consumed once but I need multiple objects to all consume the same item. Ideally, I'd also like it if the items would "disappear" on it's own after all consumers had grabbed the items.

Is there a pre-built structure in Python to handle this sort of use case? If not, any thoughts on how to most efficiently implement one myself?

Answer (score 0):

While it doesn't have the "disappearing" bit, the term for this is a readers-writer lock, and there's [a library for it here](https://pypi.org/project/readerwriterlock/).

Comment: Hi Putnam, thanks for the response. Right now, the entire object is copied into each new process, with no shared memory. I'd rather avoid using shared memory for two reasons. First, Python libraries to my understanding require a fixed bit length determined ahead of time while I vastly prefer the flexibility to scale dynamically. Secondly, shared memory adds development complexities that chew up my time (I have limited time to work on this so simplicity is paramount). If I misunderstand your answer the please elaborate.